# Extract list out of multiple sheets based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

The problem that I'm facing is concerning Excel. I'm trying to extract rows with multiple columns out of sheets based on certain criteria. I've found some solutions regarding this, but nothing is really what I'm looking for or I can't change it to make it work. I'll try to explain the issue more detailed below using an example.

Situation:

- 8 sheets (named Sh1 to Sh8) with a list of tasks
- Each sheet represents a kind of task (personal, work, ...)
- Each sheet has the same format
- Data is located starting from row 4 and between column A to K
- Below the data is a row with total calculations
- The data includes text, numbers and blank cells
- Column D is the status of the task (C for completed, I for in progress, N for not started)
- Style of the sheets is completely done by using conditional formatting

I would like something that checks those 8 sheets and copies all entries (including the blank cells) that are a certain status, being either C, I or N, to a new sheet, called "Filtering". The filtering sheet will have headers as well and the data should start at row 7.

When I started this, I came up with a formula (based on [this](http://www.exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/)) that copies all the entries of one sheet. I could filter it by putting C, I or N in the cell D4 on the filtering sheet.

```
{
=IFERROR(
         INDEX(
               Sh1!A$4:A$19;SMALL(
                                  IF(
                                      Sh1!$D$4:$D19=Filtering!$D$4;
                                      ROW(Sh1!A$4:A$19)-ROW(Sh1!A$4)+1
                                     );
                                  ROWS(Sh1!A$4:Sh1!A4)
                                 )
               );
        "")
}
```

As I said before, the data includes blank cells, so I changed the formula to the following to make sure the blank cells didn't turn into 0's:

```
{
=IFERROR(
         IF(
            INDEX(SAME AS ABOVE)="";
            "";
            INDEX(SAME AS ABOVE);
           );
         "")
}
```

Although this worked, I could only perform this on one sheet, and not on all eight. I could solve this by starting Sh2 at a lower row in the filtering sheet and do this for all other sheets, but that's not really what I'd like to get. I would really like to get to a continuous list that sums up all the not started, completed or in progress by changing that one cell D4 on the filtering sheet.

That's where I would like your suggestions. If it's possible to do this without VBA, I'd prefer that, since I sometimes use it in the online web application and macro's don't work there. If VBA is the only solution, obviously that'd be okay too.

On a side note: I tried VBA based on a code that I found [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=189039). (please have patience with me, I never coded before this) but it seems really slow to process this. Every time I run the macro, it takes more than 15 seconds to calculate this, although there are only 200 tasks that I currently have. The following was for getting all the completed tasks. I could easily make the others by changing the C to I or N. There was another problem where the whole sheet was removed, including my headers, so I'd have to put a range on the clear.

```
Sub ExtractList() 

Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim destinationWorksheet As Worksheet 
Dim columnD As Range 
Dim c As Range 
Dim count As Long 

Set destinationWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Filtering") 

destinationWorksheet.Cells.ClearContents 

count = 1 
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 

    If ws.Name = "Sh1" Or ws.Name = "Sh2" Or ws.Name = "Sh3" Or ws.Name 
    = "Sh4" Or ws.Name = "Sh5" Or ws.Name = "Sh6" Or ws.Name = "Sh7" Or
    ws.Name = "Sh8" Then

        Set columnD = ws.Range("D:D") 'columnD
        For Each c In columnD 

            If WorksheetFunction.IsText(c.Value) Then 
                If InStr(c.Value, "C") > 0 Then 
                    c.EntireRow.Copy 
                    destinationWorksheet.Cells(count, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats 
                    count = count + 1 
                End If 
            End If 
        Next c 

    End If 

Next ws 

End Sub
```

Thanks already for reading through this and I'm looking forward to your suggestions.

Cheers,
Bart

Comment: You can do this without VBA using a formula. Check out [Create a 3-D reference to the same cell range on multiple worksheets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-3-D-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-6a9cc847-547f-40e0-924a-b2ed54cc79a2)

Comment: When working with similar projects, knowing names and total sheets, I would find the last row in each sheet and copy the data to my overview (your Filtering), then have it set up sorting based on some specific column.  Similarly, you can do this and tie the cell you would like (D4) to control what is filtered, though the drop-down for sorting is also available (saves some coding)

Comment: Hi PeterT, I checked out the page that you sent me. I understand that it could check multiple sheets by using this 3-D reference, but when using a single formula in one cell, it can't show them seperately in a list, can it?

Comment: Hi Cyril, I tried this at first, copying with the link to the original cells. When I would add a line in one of the original sheets, it wouldn't appear in the filtering sheet, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is taking too long to run is because you are looping through the entire column. You need to delimit the range to work with.

This solution:

•   Allows the user to determine the extraction criteria using cell `D4` in “Filtering” worksheet (Target)

•   Sets the data ranges for each worksheet [Sh1, Sh2, Sh3, Sh4, Sh5, Sh6, Sh7, Sh8] (Source)

•   Uses `AutoFilter` to select the data required and

•   Posts the resulting ranges from all worksheets in the “Filtering” worksheet

It assumes that:

•   All worksheets involved have the same structure and headers

•   Headers are located at `A6:K6` for Target worksheet and `A3:K3` for Source worksheets (change as required)

```
Sub ExtractList()
Dim wshTrg As Worksheet, wshSrc As Worksheet
Dim sCriteria As String
Dim rDta As Range
Dim rTmp As Range, rArea As Range, lRow As Long

    Rem Set Worksheet Target
    Set wshTrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filtering")   'change as required

    Rem Clear prior data 'Header at row 6 & data starts at row 7 - change as required
    With wshTrg
        Rem Sets Criteria from Cell [D4] in target worksheet
        sCriteria = .Cells(4, 4).Value2
        .Cells(7, 1).Value = "X"    'To set range incase there is only headers
        .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).ClearContents
    End With

    Rem Process each worksheet
    lRow = 7
    For Each wshSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case wshSrc.Name
        Case "Sh1", "Sh2", "Sh3", "Sh4", "Sh5", "Sh6", "Sh7", "Sh8"
            With wshSrc
                Rem Clear AutoFilter
                If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .Cells(1).AutoFilter
                Rem Set Data Range
                Set rDta = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 11))
            End With

            With rDta
                Rem Apply AutoFilter
                .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=sCriteria
                Rem Set resulting range
                Set rTmp = .Offset(1).Resize(-1 + .Rows.count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                Rem Clear Autofilter
                .AutoFilter
            End With

            Rem Post Resulting range in target worksheet
            For Each rArea In rTmp.Areas
                With rArea
                    wshTrg.Cells(lRow, 1).Resize(.Rows.count, .Columns.count).Value = .Value2
                    lRow = lRow + .Rows.count

    End With: Next: End Select: Next
    End Sub
```

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), [Range.Offset Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx), 
[Range.SpecialCells Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx),

[Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx), [Worksheet.AutoFilter Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff823161.aspx),

[Worksheet.AutoFilterMode Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff821903.aspx), [With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx)

Comment: This is so much better! I see where I went wrong now. Your code does exactly what I'm looking for, thank you a lot. It is much appreciated. I'll check out the pages you added so I don't make the same mistakes in the future.